# Wordpress - Global Variable with Stateful Scope vs WP Options Caching Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, singleton, state

Here is the problem.

I need to increment a domain specific order number every time an order is placed in woocommerce.

I tried using the wp_option functionality, so that it would be present no matter where or when it runs.  I used the following helper functions.

```
    $this->$order_number = get_option('next_order_number'); // To retrieve next number
    update_option('next_order_number',$this->$order_number +1); // To update number

return $this->$order_number;
```

The problem I am having is that when two orders come in back to back, close enough in time, get_option is returning the same order number.

So, either the caching update is too slow or too stupid to figure out that I am accessing the same variable in both execution contexts.

In the .NET world, we could do a lot of different things to solve this.  However, I am new to wordpress and I don't have a good idea of how to handle this anomoly.

My thoughts were to create a Singleton Class, and increment the number internally and return the integer, then trigger an update to the wp_options.

Assuming the singleton worked across all wordpress requests, I could bolt on a little extra glue to grab the current value if it was reset due to a server reboot, etc...

However, even when creating a static variable for use in singleton pattern, the value isn't persisting across requests.

I am starting to think that PHP/Wordpress doesn't support any type of application state similar to Microsoft MVC.

Is there any hook or technique I can leverage where I can fire up a Global variable that persist state and live across all requests from all users, and re-init itself when the process recycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct- PHP does not hold any application state between requests, as typically it is run using a web server like Apache, which is normally configured to run an instance of PHP per request.

Instead, you'll need to save this to a database and query the database to get the number. Much like what you're doing now, but bypassing the caching options. Now, that being said, you wont want to just read the number and use it each time- because two users could attempt to read the number at the same time using different PHP processes. Instead, it's best practice to insert a row into the database with the order number as an auto-increment. This reserves this order number in the database. Then, if another user comes along at the same time and attempts to acquire an order number with that insert, it will fail, so you can try again with one number higher.

All that being said, this is normally done by default using whatever system is tracking the orders. Doesn't woocommerce already have a primary key for their orders? Why not use that? If you need a number specific to a domain, why not just count how many orders for that domain so far and save it to the order after it's created and has it's default woocommerce order number?

Comment: Mikel - Thanks for the answer, it was informative, even if I didn't want to hear it lol. The nature of the domain number is that it starts at 500000, and recycles back at the beginning a couple of times a year.  It's a weird constraint hold over from a VB6 order fulfillment application that the client uses and won't let go of.